# .net 2.0 lock and exceptions before the try-finally. Are there any other exceptions besides thread abort?

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking, .net-2.0

Today I've run into this:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/03/06/locks-and-exceptions-do-not-mix/

I am using .net 2.0, so, basically, this code

```
lock(syncRootVar) {
    DoStuff();
}
```

Will unfold into this

```
Monitor.Enter(syncRootVar);
try {
    DoStuff();
} finally {
    Monitor.Exit(syncRootVar);
}
```

As Lippert wrote on the blog, there might be a nop operation between the Enter call and the try-finally block, being a potential position for a thread abort exception to be raised and therefore messing up with the lock.

I have two questions about this:

- Is there a common way of handling this troublesome situation and still clean up the lock object in order to not affect other threads?
- Are there other situations that might result in the lock being acquired, but exceptions raising before the try-finally block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the article points out, the issue you seem to be concerned with is no longer an issue. The C# compiler has been changed (and presumably with Roslyn will retain the change) so that the lock is taken inside the `try`/`finally`. It's not possible to take the lock but fail to execute the `finally` clause.

Now (also as the article points out) you have a *different* problem: if the code in the protected block of code is mutating state, an exception could result in other code seeing partially-mutated state. This may or may not be a problem; usually it would be, but of course each specific scenario is different. It's possible some code would be safe in such a case.

> • Is there a common way of handling this troublesome situation and still clean up the lock object in order to not affect other threads?

For the specific situation you've asked about, the two biggest things you can do are:

1. Don't abort threads. This is always good advice and should always be followed. If you don't abort a thread, you won't have that problem.
2. Use the latest version of the compiler. The newer versions of the compiler don't generate code that would be susceptible to the problem.

> • Are there other situations that might result in the lock being acquired, but exceptions raising before the try-finally block?

No, not with the latest version of the compiler. There's not even the original situation.

Now what about that pesky "partially-mutated" issue? Well, you'll have to address each case individually. But if an exception might be thrown, and leaving the lock with partially-mutated state is possible, then you'll have to add your own clean-up code. E.g.:

```
lock(syncRootVar) {
    try {
        DoStuff();
    } catch {
        UndoStuff();
        throw;
    }    
}
```